# Spring bootで値を保持したままページネーションを行いたい

Tags: java, html, spring, thymeleaf, jpa

【目標】
Spring boot を使用して、検索画面の値を保持しつつ、ページネーションを行いたいです。
因みに、検索結果をDBから取得して表示させる所までは実装できています。

【質問内容】
検索画面の値を保持しつつ、ページネーションを行うコーディングを行いたいのですが、
以下の点で行き詰っています。

・検索結果画面の次のページ番号をクリックすると、次の検索結果が表示されない。
　　(Controllerに対してGetを送っているからだと思っている。。)

尚、値の保持には hidden を使用する実装にしたいです。
気付いた点やアドバイスだけでも大丈夫です。
どなたか、ご教示の程よろしくお願いします。

【使用言語、ツール等】
・Spring boot
・java
・Thymeleaf
・JPA

【ソースコード】
■添付のソースコード
TestController (Controller)
BeginDisplay.html (初期表示の検索画面)
ResultDisplay.html (検索結果の表示画面)

・TestController (Controller ) java

```
package com.example.demo.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.example.demo.entity.TestEntity;
import com.example.demo.service.TestService;

@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/lesson2")
public class TestController {

    private static final String VIEW = "ResultDisplay";



    @GetMapping("/search")
        public String startdisplay(){
            return "BeginDisplay";
        }

        @Autowired
        public TestService testservice;

        @PostMapping("/search")
        public ModelAndView search( ModelAndView mov,
                @RequestParam(name="title",required = false) String title,
                @RequestParam(name="titleKana",required = false) String titleKana,
                //@ModelAttribute SearchForm form,
                Pageable pageable
                ) {
            //ModelAndView
            //addObject(名前,保管するオブジェクト)
            mov.setViewName(VIEW);
            mov.addObject("title",title);
            mov.addObject("titleKana",titleKana);
               Page<TestEntity> resultdata = testservice.searchmaterial(title,titleKana,pageable);
                mov.addObject("result",resultdata);
                mov.addObject("resultSize", resultdata.getSize());
                mov.addObject("page",resultdata);
                return mov;
        }

}
```

・BeginDisplay.html (初期表示の検索画面)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Material Search Data</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form method="POST" action="">
  <p>タイトル　：　<input type="text" id="title" name="title" th:value="${title}"></p>
  <p>タイトルカナ　：　<input type="text" id="title_kana" name="titleKana" th:value="${titleKana}"></p>
  <p><input type="submit"  name="id" value="検索"></p>
  </form>



    <div th:if="${resultSize > 0}"><label th:text="${resultSize}"></label>件</div>
    <table border="1" th:if="${resultSize > 0}">
   <tr>
    <td>material_no</td>
    <td>title</td>
    <td>title_kana</td>
    <td>reg_date</td>
   </tr>

   <tr th:each="data : ${result}">
    <td th:text="${data.materialNo}"/>
    <td th:text="${data.title}"/>
    <td th:text="${data.titleKana}"/>
    <td th:text="${data.regDate}"/>
   </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

・ResultDisplay.html (検索結果の表示画面)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/extras/spring-security">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Material Search Data</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form method="POST" action="">
  <p>タイトル　：　<input type="text" id="title" name="title" th:value="${title}"></p>
  <input type="hidden" name="title_serach" id="title_serach" th:value="${title}">
  <p>タイトルカナ　：　<input type="text" id="title_kana" name="titleKana" th:value="${titleKana}"></p>
  <input type="hidden" name="titleKana_serach" id="titleKana_serach" th:value="${titleKana}">
  <p><input type="submit"  name="id" value="検索"></p>
  </form>



    <div th:if="${resultSize > 0}"><label th:text="${resultSize}"></label>件</div>
    <table border="1" th:if="${resultSize > 0}">
   <tr>
    <td>material_no</td>
    <td>title</td>
    <td>title_kana</td>
    <td>reg_date</td>
   </tr>

   <tr th:each="data : ${result}">
    <td th:text="${data.materialNo}"/>
    <td th:text="${data.title}"/>
    <td th:text="${data.titleKana}"/>
    <td th:text="${data.regDate}"/>
   </tr>
  </table>


 <form th:name=f th:action="@{/pagenate}" th:object="${page}" method="post">
    <div class="float-right">
      <div>
        <span th:text="${page.number+1}"></span>
        <input type="hidden" name="number_serach" id="number_serach" th:value="${page.number+1}">
    <span>/</span>
    <span th:text="${page.totalPages}"></span>
    <span>頁を表示</span>
      </div>
      <div th:fragment='paginationbar'>
        <ul>
          <li class="page-item">
              <span th:if="${page.first}">←先頭</span>
            <a th:if="${not page.first}" th:href="@{${url}(page=0)}">←先頭</a>
          </li>
          <li class="page-item" th:each='i : ${#numbers.sequence(0, page.totalPages-1)}'>
            <span th:if='${i}==${page.number}' th:text='${i+1}'>1</span>
            <a th:if='${i}!=${page.number}' th:href="@{${url}(page=${i})}">
            <input type="hidden" name="i_serach" id="i_serach" th:value="${i}">
                <span th:text='${i+1}'>1</span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="page-item">
            <span th:if="${page.last}">末尾➝</span>
            <a th:if="${not page.last}" th:href="@{${url}(page=(${page.totalPages}-1))}">末尾➝</a>           </li>
        </ul>
       </div>
     </div>
   </form>
<a href="javascript:document.f.submit()">ダウンロード</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: こちらの記事に同じ意図の実装があるようですが参考になるでしょうか(こちらでは、`HttpSession`を利用して検索語句を保持しています): https://qiita.com/t-iguchi/items/34373c1d440e8658609c

Comment: 回答される方へ　https://teratail.com/questions/284833

Comment: リンクの共有ありがとうございます。参考資料として活用させていただきましたが、 hidden で値の受け渡しを行う際に、Value が空になる点で行き詰っているので、この事象についてアドバイスを頂けたら幸いです。

Comment: 質問文からは特に手段は問わないように読み取れましたが、実際には、(HTTPセッションを使わず) POST の hidden パラメータで取り回したい、ということでしょうか。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。実証手段について、可能であればPOST(HTTPセッション)を活用して、hidden パラメータで取り回したいと思っています。また、hiddenのパラメータを訂正すべきだと思っているのですが、nameやValueなど、パラメータの指定方法がわかっていない状況です。